# How can I change theme for sidebar only?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to change theme for sidebar only?

I'd like Dark theme for sidebar and Light theme for editor.

Comment: you can change the workspace colors with the settings

Comment: I've tried it but with sth like this:
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "sideBar.background": "#241818",
        "sideBar.foreground": "#e4e4e4",
} but when I select Light theme for editor, the text color of sideBar seems to blend in with the background like this https://prnt.sc/12rnsmg, which is very hard to see.